# Why suddenly my iOS app can not post status update to Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, post, status

I was able to post a status update to Facebook user wall through the iOS app I'm developing a few days ago. Then I probably accidentally removed something, I now cannot post and get error message. The relevant code is A:

```
    message = @"test";
    [FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:message
    completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    }
```

I also tried following method B:

```
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:postParams HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id result,NSError *error)
```

and I got same error message: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)"

I also noticed doesn't matter if I use FacebookSDK.h or Facebook.h for either method, both (four ways) would all get the same error message above. I also wonder why FacebookSDK.h is enough to support two methods above, why the tutorial suggests deprecated Facebook.h.

Interesting, I went to check another testing iOS app that I remember could post Facebook status update, and found it could not post either. Any idea?

Comment: getting same error msg !! guess it has something to do with the modifications done in FacebookSDK for iOS 6. !!

Comment: Boy! I've been spending a day or so on this problem. Hope others can confirm the same phenomenon so that we know it's Facebook's problem.

Comment: What permissions have you requested to be able to post the status update?

Comment: I have "post on your behalf" and "access posts on your news feed". Suppose the first one would authorize my app to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use iOS6 feature SLComposeViewController, which makes posting Facebook status update a piece of cake.

After add Social framework  in your .m file, you can do sth like this:

```
    - (IBAction)clickMe:(UIButton *)sender {
         NSLog(@"you clicked me");
         if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

       SLComposeViewController* myFB = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];


          SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"cancelled");
           } else {
               NSLog(@"oh yeah");
           }
        [myFB dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    };
    myFB.completionHandler = myBlock;
    [myFB setInitialText:@"Posting from my app."];
    [self presentViewController:myFB animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

    }
```