# HTTP status code 400 when posting to facebook FBiOSSDK.3.0.8

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

i am using the ios sdk 3.0 to post simple text to user facebook wall , below is the code is use to post to facebook

```
[FBRequestConnection
 startForPostStatusUpdate:text completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                     id result,
                     NSError *error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        NSLog(@"the status posted");
    }
}];
```

but i get the error from facebook like

FBSDKLog: Response <#1115> :
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.) . any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer to you question.
I'm having the same problem, and I posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540895/why-suddenly-my-ios-app-can-not-post-status-update-to-facebook

Answer (score 0):

The bug is if you try to share an NSString.

This works:

[FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:@"test"
                                        completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                           }];

This gives you the error:

NSString *testString = @"test";
[FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:testString
                                        completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                           }];